# Auto-login on account activation

Tags: config, login, registration, activation

Anybody got any suggestions on debugging `autoLoginAfterAccountActivation` and `activateAccountSuccessPath` not working?

These are set in `general.php` of my config but when a user activates their account (sets their password) they are redirected to the homepage and not logged in. The user is showing as active in the control panel.

Hayelp!

[Hayelp! http://www.cartoonscrapbook.com/01pics-L/penelope-pitstop_L20.jpg](http://www.cartoonscrapbook.com/01pics-L/penelope-pitstop_L20.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Not necessarily a great answer to your question, but it's in the same wheelhouse and might be handy if you're working in this area)!

I remember having issues with this myself (to be honest the precise details are a bit lost in time for me - but basically IIRC it's by design that they're not logged in after creation, perhaps to force them to practise login/their password?  I can't remember but do remember I found it odd behavour) - anyway in my case the issues arose as part of adding user registration during commerce checkout.  It was discussed on Slack and the solution was that Steve Rowling made a very handy plugin to auto-login newly created users:
https://github.com/steverowling/autologin

I'm using it, works a treat.

(I should also wrap up my code for registration during checkout as a plugin and release that one of these days!)

Comment: Okay, so further to this have been able to login with Steve Rowling's excellent plugin. However can't seem to specify where a user is directed to on login. For example via the `postLoginRedirect` or `activateAccountSuccessPath` config. Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: hmmm I think `activateAccountSuccessPath` should work to be honest - what does your config look like - when we have new users register, they definitely go to their dashboard, so it's working here (this is for new user registration right?)

Comment: Hey Jeremy - the setting is `'activateAccountSuccessPath' => 'account',` but (new) user registrations are still being sent to the site root. Ta

Answer (score 2):

Add `'autoLoginAfterAccountActivation' => true` to config/general.php

Link: https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/config/config-settings.html#autologinafteraccountactivation