# Autologin destination

Tags: users, login, registration, activation

A bit of an extension of my previous query at [Auto-login on account activation](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/16658/auto-login-on-account-activation)

I want to a user to:

1. automatically login on account activation, and
2. be redirected to a predetermined page on account activation.

Thanks to @steverowling managed to do the former using his autologin plugin([1](https://github.com/steverowling/autologin)). However struggling with the latter. I can't see how to specify the redirect location and on activation/login the user is always redirected to the site homepage.

Any thoughts on how to specify a redirect destination in conjunction with the above functionality?

Cole

Answer (score 3):

Okay - got to the bottom of this.
Was using the wrong setting. Should have been `setPasswordSuccessPath` not `setPasswordSuccess`!